# how to get data using winhttprequest using asp classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have written code using asp classic and vb-script in `payment.asp`. i am posting data to 3rd party using winhttprequest and its submitting successfully and it works fine but my issue is:

after posting data, on 3rd party page, there is creating a unique ID which i want to retrieve on same page `payment.asp`

how can i retrieve unique ID created by 3rd party.

My code is as below given:

```
<%
Dim http, url, data
Set http = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
url = "https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/"
data = "amount=" & amount & "&buyer_name=" & buyer_name & "&purpose=" & purpose & "&redirect_url=" & redirect_url & "&phone=" & phone & "&send_email=" & send_email & "&send_sms=" & send_sms & "&email=" & email & ""

With http
Call .Open("POST", url, False)
Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
Call .SetRequestHeader("X-Api-Key", "[X-Api-Key]")
Call .SetRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", "[X-Auth-Token]")
Call .Send(data)
 End With

If http.Status = 201 Then
Call Response.Write("succeeded: " & http.Status & " " & http.StatusText)
Else
Call Response.Write("Server returned: " & http.Status & " " & http.StatusText)
End If
%>
```

please help me.

Comment: Did you forget [the conversation](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113121/discussion-between-lokesh-purohit-and-lankymart#) we had about ASPJSON and `http.ResponseText`? Guess so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](http://docs.instamojo.com/docs/create-a-request) the API's results are formatted in JSON. So you'll need a JSON parser like [ASPJSON](http://aspjson.com/).

Include the `aspJSON1.17.asp` in your `payment.asp` and
after getting the response with 201 status code, parse the ID like this:

```
Set oJSON = New aspJSON
    oJSON.loadJSON http.ResponseText

Response.Write oJSON.data("payment_request")("id")
```

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure [I suggested this yesterday](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113121/discussion-between-lokesh-purohit-and-lankymart#).

Comment: @Lankymart you really did, almost exactly the same words :) maybe this will help him to understand the concept.

Comment: @Lankymart, thanks for remembering me for aspjson, Now it retrieve values and work perfect.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin, thanks bro for your code given me good idea. it works perfect.